# Can one prevent SQL injection by customizing # -- /**/ tags and ; DELIMITER?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-injection

As I understand, most SQL injection is done by inserting a malicious piece of SQL and commenting out the remainder of the query.

Of course this would only be an additional layer on top of known and proven best practices but is it possible to simply change the comment tags from the defaults of `#`, `--`, and `/*...*/` to something a little less attacker friendly as in `noInject (remainder of comment here)`? so that the query throws an error rather than completing?

And further by changing the `;` delimiter to something like `eol` or `\|/`

I'm using MySQL, but as a general question would this be worth the effort?

Comment: Just use parameters. Trying to make string concatenation "safe" from SQL Injection always seems pointless given that practically every language binding to SQL that you'll find these days offers parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Even if* such a change were possible (which it's not, unless you fork the MySQL source code and compile your own—not feasible with SQL Server) and would cause *some* injections to fail, it wouldn't catch them all.

Let's imagine a PHP-driven website through which users can view their medical records.  To enable the user to filter his records for those related to a particular illness, one permits the illness to be specified by its `id` as a query parameter:

http://www.example.com/health/fetchmyrecords.php?illness=123

The developer, relying on the fact that the server has been modified, makes no further effort to protect against SQL injection, so then does something like this:

```php
print_r(
  $pdo->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM   health_records
    WHERE  user    = $_SESSION[uid]
       AND illness = $_GET[illness]
  ")
  ->fetchAll()
);
```

Now suppose that user `987` requests the following URI:

http://www.example.com/health/fetchmyrecords.php?illness=123+OR+1%3D1

Consequently the RDBMS will receive the following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   health_records
WHERE  user    = 987
   AND illness = 123 OR 1=1
```

**SQL successfully injected!**  In this particular example the injection is *fatal*, since the RDBMS will parse that `WHERE` clause as:

```sql
WHERE (user = 987 AND illness = 123) OR 1=1
```

…so it will actually return *every health record of every user in the database*!

<sup>Good luck affording the legal fees that will come out of that.  It's a reasonable guess that your business will collapse, your personal finances will be ruined, your house will be repossessed, your wife will leave you, your kids won't speak to you and your cat will run away!</sup>

The explanation (for the injection, not your cat's disappearance) is that none of the tokens that you modified were required!

But let's suppose that you went further and modified *every single token* in order that any previously valid SQL injection would now result in an error: you *still* haven't protected against SQL injection, as an attacker need merely alter his attack to use your customised SQL variant.  You have achieved little more than [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), which is not secure at all.

As [@Nanne has stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23403065/623041), parameterising your queries is *the* correct way to defeat SQL injection attacks (at least, those that attack literal values—if you accept untrusted values into other language tokens you will need to protect yourself in some other way, although that's a rare requirement and well beyond the scope of this answer).

Comment: I see. So if I were still to chase this, I would have to rewrite/customize the entire language, Which would make everything a pain for anybody else who would have to deal with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> As I understand, most SQL injection is done by inserting a malicious piece of SQL and commenting out the remainder of the query.

Your assumption is plain wrong.

Although it is required that the resulting SQL is valid, using comments is just one (and probably the easiest) way of skipping parts of the SQL. However, one can still build perfect SQL via injection without any comments.

Better stick to the known and proven best practices.

Answer (score 2):

It is not worth the effort. The best way to prevent this kind of injection is to separate code (SQL) from content (your data).

The data is the stuff they put the comments in, so if you **know** is may not be SQL, you don't have a problem.

This is called parametrization, and that is your first step to winning the internet :)

What you do is tell the function that puts stuff in SQL that

1. this is my code (sql), for instance `SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE something = ?`
2. the `?` means: here comes data!
3. You then say what dat should be on the place of the `?` in a functions that is made to do that.
4. ...
5. profit!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to change the statement delimiter in MySQL multi-query. The `DELIMITER` command only affects the statement delimiter in the `mysql` client, not in server-side dynamic SQL parsing. So `DELIMITER` is not recognized by the server, and therefore is not usable as you write code in any application language like PHP, Java, Ruby, Python, etc. `DELIMITER` works only in SQL scripts you run with the `mysql` client.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html says:

> MySQL 5.6 also supports the execution of a string containing multiple statements separated by semicolon (“;”) characters.

But the presence of semicolons in multi-query syntax is far from the only way, or even the most common way, that SQL injection can harm your system. Even if you could change the delimiter in dynamic SQL, it wouldn't be much of a defense.

Use the usual recommended defenses, and semicolons won't be a threat anyway:

- Parameterized queries
- Whitelisting identifiers